# Remove Sharepoint permissions with Powershell when folder is created in Sharepoint Library

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, active-directory

I have a Sharepoint Library, which I have mapped out to my Z:\ drive.

I have a script, that drops user specific files, in folders that I create with the following chunk of Powershell:

```
#If the output path doesn't exist, make it quietly.
If(!(Test-Path "z:\$strOwnerName")){$null = New-Item "Z:\$strOwnerName" -ItemType directory}
```

How can I (if at all possible) modify this line to remove/restrict permissions for everyone in Sharepoint, aside from the user for which the folder is being created? The folder name, will always be the users AD name.

Comment: Do you mind having a folder with no access aside from accounts/groups like Administrators and SYSTEM (things you wouldn't want to remove anyway)? I can give you an easy answer if that's the case.

Comment: That would work, except the 'Administrators' might be an issue, let's see what you got!

Comment: To clarify, the 'Administrators' might be an issue because some of the users that would be traversing the root directory would be admins. I meant to edit that previous comment @TheMadTechnician however I was 1 minute too late to the party. Thanks!

Comment: Well, it's up to you as to who has access rights to the folder you use as a basic template, but I know most system administrators will get a bit grumpy if there's folders on their servers that they can't touch. I would at least leave yourself with full control over the ACL Template folder though, so if they do come after you about it you can grant them access as needed. Or maybe setup a service account and give it access so that the folders can be modified as needed via that account.

Comment: I just realized I was adding and removing permissions based on NTFS Access Control List and not SharePoint (unless they are one and the same, but I doubt it). Sorry, my answer is probably useless to you.

Answer (score 2):

I'd start with a folder that has just very basic permissions, so you have something to copy. Then add the permission for the new folder's owner onto the ACL object. Lastly create the folder and apply the modified ACL to it. I Selected Read, Write, Modify, and DeleteSubdirectoryAndFiles but you can pick and choose your security settings for the user from [this list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.accesscontrol.filesystemrights.aspx).

```
$colRights = [System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights]"Read, Write, Modify, DeleteSubdirectoriesAndFiles" 

$InheritanceFlag = [System.Security.AccessControl.InheritanceFlags]::None 
$PropagationFlag = [System.Security.AccessControl.PropagationFlags]::None 

$objType =[System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType]::Allow 

$objUser = New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount("DigitalGhost\$strOwnerName") 

$objACE = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule `
    ($objUser, $colRights, $InheritanceFlag, $PropagationFlag, $objType) 

$objACL = Get-ACL "Z:\ACLSource" 
$objACL.AddAccessRule($objACE) 

#If the output path doesn't exist, make it quietly.
If(!(Test-Path "z:\$strOwnerName")){$null = New-Item "Z:\$strOwnerName" -ItemType directory}


Set-ACL "Z:\$strOwnerName" $objACL
```

And of coarse, credit where credit is due... I picked most of that up directly a while ago off of [this TechNet Windows PowerShell Tip of the Week](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730951.aspx).